# NotesXSPDocument and NotesDocument

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I have created a function in SSJS Library. Because I use it in more than one XPages.

When I call this function behind a button I cannot see the value in the field
If I print it out I can see the value at the Admin Console but cannot see it in the form Even if I get page with full refreshed.

Actually my another question is.. is it possible to compare notesXSPDocument and NotesDocument. Maybe someoen can say that what is the best way for that?

```
function deneme(document1:NotesXSPDocument,otherDocfromOtherDatabase:NotesDocument)
            {
                //do staff here
               if (document1.getItemValueString("field1")==otherDocfromOtherDatabase.getItemValueString("field2"))
   { //do some staff here...
                document1.replaceItemValue("fieldName","FieldValue");}
            }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=compare+strings+java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare item values from Document and XSPDocument, just be careful with the type you are comparing.

In your code you are comparing 2 javascript strings with == operator.
The code seems to be OK, just remember to save the document1 after the changes and maybe check that the items have some value.

```
var valueFromXspDoc = document1.getItemValueString("field1");
var valueFromDoc = otherDocfromOtherDatabase.getItemValueString("field2");

if (valueFromXspDoc && valueFromDoc && (valueFromXspDoc === valueFromDoc)) {
    // stuff here...
    document1.replaceItemValue("fieldName","FieldValue");
    document1.save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don not compare it with == sign. A better way is to document1.getItemValueString("field1").equals(otherDocfromOtherDatabase.getItemValueString("field2"))